# Solving $x^2 + 7x \equiv 1\pmod{13}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How should I solve this particular congruence:  $x^2 + 7x \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$?
I can re-arrange the equation to get $$x^2 + 7x - 1 \equiv_{13} 0$$. In noticing that $7 \equiv_{13} -6$, can I replace $7x$ by $-6x$ in order that the middle term should be preceded by an even coefficient?

Comment: Does it help you to do that? What if you noticed $-1 \equiv_{13}  12$?

Comment: Brute force will be faster than anything else.

Comment: `\pmod{13}` automatically gives you the space, the typeface, and the parentheses.

Comment: As in the dupe, the quadratic formula (completing the square) works over any field. Here the discriminant is $53\equiv 1$ so the roots are $\,(-7\pm 1)/2 \equiv (6\pm 14)/2\equiv 3\pm 7\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x^2 + 7x - 1 \equiv_{13} 0$ is the same as $x^2 + 7x + 12 \equiv_{13} 0$. Now note that the left hand side factors as $(x+4)(x+3)$. So, $x = -3,-4$ i.e. $x = 9,10$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).